# separate alphanumeric data in SQL with two delimiters like ; and -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like "A001; A009; A011-A015; A055; B101-B104"

The ; will only split the data into rows.

```
+------+
| A001 | 
+------+
| A009 | 
+------+
| A055 | 
+------+
```

The - will only split the data into rows.

```
+------+
| A011 | 
+------+
| A012 | 
+------+
| A013 | 
+------+
| A014 | 
+------+
| A015 | 
+------+
| B101 | 
+------+
| B102 | 
+------+
| B103 | 
+------+
| B104 | 
+------+
```

How can a SQL query do that?

Comment: Your data is very challenging to work with to say the least. You have a lot of hurdles here. First you have to split this into rows on the semicolon. Then you have to expand rows that have a - in them. Yuck. Do you always have 1 character followed by three numbers or is this just sample data and your real data is not that consistent?

Comment: That's not a job for SQL, the language. This would be easy to do with regular expressions or a parser.

Comment: Yes I am looking for both

Answer (score 0):

this will do the dashed split

maybe create a table valued function to return the result set

```
declare @dashed varchar(100) = 'A005-A015'

declare @start int = cast(substring(@dashed,2,3) as int)
    ,@end int = cast(substring(@dashed,7,3) as int)
    ,@prefix varchar(1) = left(@dashed,1)
declare @val int = @start

declare @t table(vals varchar(10))

while(@val<=@end)
BEGIN
    insert into @t values(@prefix + RIGHT('00'+CAST(@val as varchar(3)),3))
    set @val=@val+1
END

select * from @t




--Tally solution

--This should be done once for real and never have to do it again
declare @t2 table (num int)
declare @i int = 0

while(@i <200)
BEGIN 
    insert into @t2 values(@i)
    set @i=@i+1
END

select @prefix + RIGHT('00'+CAST(num as varchar(3)),3)
from @t2
where num between @start and @end
```

Comment: A tally table would be better than a while loop. The real challenge though is we don't know if these are fixed length or not.

Comment: I added it as an option.